# Magento - How can I add or remove a custom option from a product in the cart?

Tags: magento, edit, cart

I'm trying to add or remove custom options from a product in the cart. The custom options are defined against the product itself in the back end, I'm not trying to make up a new custom option dynamically or anything like that. All of my custom options are single checkboxes, in case it makes a difference.

I'm using an observer on `checkout_cart_update_items_after` and looping through `Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getAllItems()`. I can see which items currently have a custom option selected using

```
$orderOptions = $item->getProduct()->getTypeInstance(true)->getOrderOptions($item->getProduct());
if ( isset($orderOptions['info_buyRequest']['options']) )
    // cart item has options selected.
```

In the first instance I'd really like to be able to remove these custom options. I expected to be able to find something like `$item->removeOption($optionId);`, but I can't find any way of doing this.

In the second instance I'd really like to be able to add a custom option to an item. I've tried various ways of doing this including `$item->addOption(array('code'=>$optionCode, 'value'=>1));`.

I can't get either to work, and I'm sure I'm just missing something quite simple. Can you help?

Comment: Do you want to specify custom product options on-the-fly on quote items ?

Comment: I'd like to add a checkbox next to custom options in the cart, which I have done. I'd like to remove the custom option from the cart item if the customer unticks the box and clicks "update cart". I can detect the customer unticking the box in my observer and detect which cart item they wish to change. The custom product options themselves are specified in the back end when editing the product.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to specify custom product options on-the-fly on quote items (Ex:adding Delivery date with each product in the orders), you can make use of an observer toadd a custom option.

Example:

```
<controller_action_predispatch_checkout>
<observers>
<options_observer>
<class>YOUR_CLASS_NAME</class>
<method>setProductInfo</method>
</options_observer>
</observers>
</controller_action_predispatch_checkout>


$deliveryDate = $prId['delivery_date'];
if (!empty($deliveryDate)) {
$opt['options'] = array($optionID => $deliveryDate);
$request->setParams($opt);
}
return $this;
```

Another way to add option is

```
$item->addOption(array(
    'code' => 'additional_options',
    'value' => serialize($additionalOptions),
));
```

Suppose you have below option

```
$option = array(
    'title' => 'Auto Date & Time',
    'type' => 'date_time',
    'is_require' => 1,
    'sort_order' => 0,
    'is_delete' => '',
    'previous_type' => '',
    'previous_group' => '',
    'price' => '0.00',
    'price_type' => 'fixed',
    'sku' => ''
);
```

Fetch `$product->getOptionInstance()` directly

```
$product->getOptionInstance()->addOption($option);

$product->setHasOptions(true); //mention that the product has custom options
```

**To delete the custom option:**

```
if($product->getOptions() != ''{
  foreach ($product->getOptions() as $opt){
     $opt->delete(); 
   } 
 $product->setHasOptions(0)->save();
}
```

Hope it helps !!!

Comment: Thanks! Your code for deleting custom options works like a dream. I'm working on adding an option to an item in the cart and your code gives me the error `Fatal error: Call to a member function addOption() on a non-object`. Can you help any more?

Comment: I've got them both working now, but they only work once! If I add an option I cannot remove it, if I remove an option I cannot add a new option. I think I'm doing something slightly wrong, and I'll figure it out, but you've certainly given me a very good start. Thanks!